# Types in php, retype them and use their variables

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-conversion

Is there a possibility use "data types" in php?
I have class Page, it has variables (I use public, I don't need private in my case, there is no security risk, etc.). I create some Objects of my class add them to array, then I go trought them by **foreach** and I wanna **use** iterated object in foreach like my Page object. So I wanna let know my ide (PhpStorm) know that the object from array is type of Page, so he can whisper me his variables. 
In Java I would do something like this **(Page) myObject**. Than the ide know "Juhuu programmer say, that myObject should be type of Page, so I let him to work him like with Page object not just like some general object"

**Code bellow should explain more my problem:**

**NOTE:** 
I know that I can write inside foreach page->$url; and it will works. But how the hell I should remember all names of variables. More likely I don't want to remember them or have to find them, I want them whispered.

```
class Page {
   public $url;
   public $array_of_titles;
   //...
   function __construct($url,$tit) {
     $this->url = $url;
     $this->array_of_titles = $tit;
   }
}
$array_of_pages = array();
$url = "http://..."
$tit = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}
$page = new Page($url, $tit);
$array_of_pages[] = $page;
//... add more pages to the array
foreach($array_of_pages as $page) {
   $my_url = $page->url; //this words but don't whisper obviously
   //because in $page could by any object
   //$my_url = (Page)$page->url; //this I would do in java to say 
   //"Hey $page is typeof Page man, I wanna whisper its methods"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the @var annotation like so:

```
foreach($allPages as $page)
{
    /*
    * @var PageType $page 
    */
    $page->doesSomething();
}
```

The @var takes the class type and the variable it applies to, you can also dictate that an array is an array of classes using `MyObjectType[]` at the declaration in the class or the instantiation (iirc).

Also, using `private` and `protected` instead of `public` is more about good programming design than security and I recommend you read about it, as well as Polymorphism and inheritance.

Comment: In PHPStorm specifically it doesn't matter which way around you place the data type and variable. PHP and it's tools can be a strange bunch some times. I'm still yearning for fully strict type hinting (not just objects) in PHP

Comment: thanks Everon, that's nice to know... And in regard to your strict type hinting... Please bite the bullet and use C# instead. I insist.

Comment: The notation is /* @var $variable Type */ in Netbeans - Odd considering all language notation is Type variable but oh well.. that's Javadoc for you

Comment: Ahaha, I've considered it at times believe me. C# is lovely to work with when I need it for desktop apps but beyond that I'll stick with PHP :)

Comment: I've used Laravel for a year now. I've used many other PHP frameworks for the last 8 years. C# MVC 4.0 tops them all by far... C# type safety is a life saver... .NET MVC Is a great platform for web development. But each to their own :) - Recommended learning book including dependency injection, repositories, ORM - "Pro ASP.Net MVC 5 (Expert's Voice in ASP.Net) " - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-Net-MVC-Experts-Voice/dp/1430265299/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1422231362&sr=8-2&keywords=ASP+NEt+MVC5

Comment: Dependency Injection is king, Laravel is my god and the Laracasts may be my Muse. May be in PHP 6 in 2020? I started out writing vanilla PHP code and using require/include then moved to Code Igniter which was quickly abandoned for Laravel 4 and now I'm eagerly waiting for 5.0.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? 
foreach($array_of_pages as $page) { 
/* @var Page $page */
$url = $page-> //no whispering :/
}

Comment: If the class is name spaced, ensure the class is imported else PHPStorm won't know which class you're referring to, else use the fully qualified class name. PHPStorm has to already know about the class which is usually accomplished by an autoloader by Composer (if you're using Composer which I would recommend). When hovering your mouse over the class type and holding control it should become bold and allow you to click to view the definition of the class.

Comment: Private and protected instead of public => I use it just as object for some parser for analysing page code. I used public because I am lazy. Normaly I would use private and protected but in this case it brings only overhead with getters and setters.

Comment: But what if you needed to add functionality that was coupled with retrieving and/or setting the data held by the class object? You would have to rewrite multiple parts of your application. Save yourself the work, think ahead (imo).

Comment: If you can't get the /* var Page $page */  to work, please try /* var $page Page */ It's how it's documented in Javadoc - With the @ sign, the comment won't allow me to @ lol!

Comment: @Everon I have file objects.php and I have definition of class Page in that file. This code is in file analysis.php and at start of file is require_once("objects.php");
I don't use composer yet. This is just simple utitlity script .. 
I there any mistake I do? 
On new Page(...) the definiton of page works but on /* var Page $page */ it doesn't work.
(btw I don't know how to write that email tag in comments before var so its not here)

Comment: Both `/* @var Page $page */ `or `/* @var $page Page */` somehow doesn't work
I mean no whispering :/

Comment: Java doc doesn't really apply here, it's still for PHP/PHPStorm. The single line comment won't work. I know the syntax is very similar.
@user1097772 Ensure you have code hints enabled and test this all in another class/file to ensure that every thing is working as expected.